# Print a Member of Struct in a Vector of Lists of Structs

Tags: c++, list, vector, struct

I have a struct; it looks like this:

```
struct Edge {                                                   //Represents an edge
    int v1, v2;                                             // From vertex, To vertex
    double weight;                                          // Edge weight
    Edge(int vertex1, int vertex2, double wt) :             // Edge constructor
        v1{ vertex1 }, v2{ vertex2 }, weight{ wt } {};        // from, to, weight
};
```

I have a vector of lists of these structs; it looks like this:

```
vector<list<Edge>> adjacent;
```

I've already got my vector of lists initialized, but I can't figure out how to print the weight member of all my edges.

```
list<Edge> ::iterator gr;               //list iterator
    for (int x = 0; x < numVertices; x++) {
        for (gr = adjacent[x].begin(); gr != adjacent[x].end(); ++gr) {
            cout << *gr.weight;
        }
    }
```

This does not work. VS tells me it does not have a member "weight". Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

`*gr.weight` does not deference `iterator` first. It is equivalen to `*(gr.weight)`.

Change this to `(*gr).weight` or `gr->weight;`

Answer (score 1):

`gr` is an iterator, which in many respects behaves like a pointer, so you should use `gr->weight` rather than `*gr.weight`.

---

Consider range-based `for` loops instead:

```
for (const auto &edgeList : adjacent)
{
    for (const auto &edge : edgeList)
    {
        cout << edge.weight << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
cout << gr->weight;
```

Also equivalent to doing:

```
cout << (*gr).weight;
```

The reason why yours did not compile is because of [`operator precedence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence):

The `*a` (indirection) operator has a lower precedence than the `.` (member-access) operator. So in your case, it was trying to find a member of the iterator called `weight`, which failed.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Just wondering, why doesn't it work if I dereference it?

Comment: @OldIslander the answer to that has to do with [`operator predence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedenc). The `*a` (indirection) operator has a lower precedence than the `.` (member-access) operator. So in your case, it was trying to find a member of the iterator called `weight`, which failed.